# How to show my results in r, based on different number of studies in each ID

Tags: r

I have this following data which is a subset of large data, note that I have different number of id.

```
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
year <- c(1978, 1983, 1974, 1989, 1974, 2002, 1990, 1974, 1998, 1989, 1974, 1983, 1978, 1998, 1978, 1974, 1974, 1998)
y <- c(-0.81, -0.87, -0.67, -0.77, -0.03, -0.94, -0.78, -0.12, -0.34, -0.55, -0.99, -0.44, -0.14, -0.34, -0.76, -0.87, -0.45, -0.84)
s <- c(0.11, 0.19, 0.05, 0.17, 0.09, 0.03, 0.08, 0.22, 0.21, 0.15, 0.09, 0.02, 0.11, 0.03, 0.09, 0.27, 0.15, 0.04)

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, year, y, s))
```

For each unique id I'm taking the first 3 rows (studies) to predict the remaing studies in that id. I was able to write the code but I could not store them. I use [i,j] but they are not right.
Here is my try

```
data.ids <- unique(data$id)
for(i in 1:length(data.ids)){
  temp <-data[data$id == data.ids[i],]
  # sorting id by year
  temp <- temp[order(temp$year),]   
  
  # start with 3 studies to predict the remainng 
  list <- lapply(4:nrow(temp)-1, function(k) head(temp, k))

  for(j in 1:length(list)){
    sub.data <- as.data.frame(list[j])
    
    new.id[i,j] <- data.ids[i]
    
    # number of studies in each predict
    ns <- nrow(sub.data)
    result <- rma(yi = sub.data$y, vi = sub.data$s)
    alpha <- 0.05
    # To get PI for each list
    lower.PI[i,j] <- result$b - qt(1-alpha/2,ns-2)*sqrt(result$tau2 + (result$se.tau2)^2)
    upper.PI[i,j] <- result$b + qt(1-alpha/2,ns-2)*sqrt(result$tau2 + (result$se.tau2)^2)
  }
}
```

This is the desire results,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several objects that are not defined that you keep modifying: `new.id`, `ns`, `lower.PI`, `upper.PI`, `n`. I am guessing `n=5` for the code below, that seems to work. I would recommend working with lists and `lapply`/`Map`/`sapply`/etc instead of `for` loops.

```
data <- data[order(data$year), ]
l <- lapply(split(data, data$id), function(x) {
  idx  <- 4:nrow(x) - 1
  list <- Map(head, list(x), idx)
  res  <- sapply(list, function(y) {
    result <- metafor::rma(yi = y$y, vi = y$s)
    n <- 5
    alpha <- 0.05
    c(lower = result$b - qt(1-alpha/2,n-2)*sqrt(result$tau2 + (result$se.tau2)^2),
      upper = result$b + qt(1-alpha/2,n-2)*sqrt(result$tau2 + (result$se.tau2)^2))
  })
  data.frame(new.id = x$id[1], list.num = seq_along(idx), ns = idx, PI = t(res))
})

final.data <- do.call('rbind', l)
rownames(final.data) <- NULL
final.data

#   new.id list.num ns   PI.lower    PI.upper
# 1      1        1  3 -1.3777758  0.69622303
# 2      1        2  4 -1.3002323  0.38622002
# 3      1        3  5 -1.2108996  0.18125764
# 4      1        4  6 -1.0687529 -0.02578397
# 5      1        5  7 -0.8828216 -0.29983494
# 6      1        6  8 -0.7504812 -0.40104346
# 7      2        1  3 -1.4024718  0.37016603
# 8      2        2  4 -0.9875005 -0.02997794
# 9      3        1  3 -1.1492804 -0.21623680
```

Comment: Thank you for ur response, n in my code is ns in each data. I'll take a close look hopefully it work with my data